# Firebase : Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.positivethinkers.Members

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am facing the following error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type

I have a problem with:

```
members = ds.getValue(Members.class);
listdata.add(members);
```

Help me solve this error.

```
reference = fbd.getReference().child("Members");
        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    members = new Members();
                    members = ds.getValue(Members.class);
                    listdata.add(members);


                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adpter);
                adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

Here Model Class

```
package com.example.positivethinkers;

public class Members {

String member_name;
String father_name;
String mobile;
String email;
String nid;
String address;
String password;
String balance;
String notify;
String occupation;
String prolink;
String nick;


public Members() {
}

public Members(String member_name, String mobile, String email, String prolink) {
    this.member_name = member_name;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.email = email;
    this.prolink = prolink;
}

public Members(String member_name, String father_name, String mobile, String email, String nid, String address, String password, String balance, String notify, String occupation, String prolink, String nick) {
    this.member_name = member_name;
    this.father_name = father_name;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.email = email;
    this.nid = nid;
    this.address = address;
    this.password = password;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.notify = notify;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.prolink = prolink;
    this.nick = prolink;
}



public String getMember_name() {
    return member_name;
}

public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
    this.member_name = member_name;
}

public String getFather_name() {
    return father_name;
}

public void setFather_name(String father_name) {
    this.father_name = father_name;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNid() {
    return nid;
}

public void setNid(String nid) {
    this.nid = nid;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(String balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String getNotify() {
    return notify;
}

public void setNotify(String notify) {
    this.notify = notify;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return occupation;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public String getProlink() {
    return prolink;
}

public void setProlink(String prolink) {
    this.prolink = prolink;
}

public String getNick() {
    return nick;
}

public void setNick(String nick) {
    this.nick = nick;
}

}
```

Here My Database

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.positivethinkers.Members

Because you are looping through the `dataSnapshot` object which contains String properties and not `Members` objects. When you add a `ChildEventListener` on the `Members` node, `onChildAdded()` method is called for each and every child that exists within that node. So there is no need for an iteration. To solve this, simply remove that for loop like in the following lines of code:

```
reference = fbd.getReference().child("Members");
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        members = new Members();
        members = ds.getValue(Members.class);
        listdata.add(members);
        adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Before that, create the adapter with an empty list and inside the callback just notify it about the changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        members = new Members();
                        String name = ds.child("member_name").getValue(String.class);
                        String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        String mobile = ds.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
                        String profile = ds.child("prolink").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", name + " / "+email+" / "+mobile+" / "+profile);
                        Members members = new Members(name, mobile, email, profile);
                        listdata.add(members);
                    }
}
```